# Setting the size of the horizontal axis within BarChart

Tags: charts

Within `BarChart` is there a way to increase the length of the horizontal axis in order for me to be able to fit in a description on the right side?
Below is an example where I used another bar with the value(s) 0 so that my description has some space on the side. However, I am sure there is a real solution to that.

```
BarChart[{{3, 2}, {0, 0}}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  Epilog -> 
    {Red,
     braceLabel[{{1.6, 4}, {1.6, 2}}, Style["label", Larger], .02], 
     Dashed, Line[{{0.5, 4}, {1.55, 4}}], Dashed, Line[{{0.5, 2}, {1.55, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your definition for `bracelevel` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `PlotRangePadding` to enlarge the plot viewport to include the graphics specified in the epilog.

```
BarChart[{3, 2},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .55}, .2},
  Epilog -> {Red, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], Rectangle[{1.55, 2}, {2.05, 4}]}]
```

chart[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html).  You did not include your definition of `braceLabel`

```
BarChart[{3, 2},
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
   Line[{{0.5, 4}, {1.55, 4}}],
   Line[{{0.5, 2}, {1.55, 2}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 2.5}, Automatic},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

Comment: ty m_goldberg and bob hanlon. both answers work very well!